# Discover Meteor app not routing correctly

Tags: meteor

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() { return Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

It's routing to the right path but not updating the template view

I deployed the app to 
http://microscope-1.meteor.com/

and here's the link to that repository
https://github.com/sdybskiy/microscope-1.0

Comment: Please post relevant code and the most exact nature of your problem you can discover. Also there is no need to thank or congratulate people on SO.

Comment: @greggreg my apologies, new at this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Discover Meteor isn't updated for the newest version of `iron:router`. Try adding the previous version with `meteor add iron:router@0.9.4`.

Comment: The url is getting updated to i.e. localhost:3000/posts/TEBdzxnD97B7hw5MS however it doesn't grab the template for postPage.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

meteor remove iron:router
meteor add iron:router@1.0.0-pre4

Works for me!!!!